# Electrophilic attack of X+ on double bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, electrophilic-substitution, c-x-addition

Is it the double bond attacking the $\ce{X+}$ ion or the other way around?

Also, does it form a cyclic transition state if it isn't bromine or chlorine?

Eg. cyclohexene $+ \,\ce{Cl+ ->}$ cyclic transition state

But would the same thing happen if I put any other electrophile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of reactions are called Electrophilic addition reactions. These are usually given by alkenes and alkynes. In your example, the electrophile is $\ce{Cl+}$. The alkene will act as a source of π electrons and will donate it to the electrophile which is in need of electrons. So, alkene is called as nucleophile in this reaction.

> Is it the double bond attacking the X+ ion or the other way around?

It depends on how you look at it. We can say that alkene polarizes the $\ce{Cl-Cl}$ bond by pushing electrons into the anti-bonding molecular orbital. This weakens the bond and hence electrophile is getting generated. In the next step,the electrophile attacks the double bond [or double bond attacks the electrophile] and hence electrophile gets added across across the double bond

**Why does the 3-membered cyclic transition state form?**

The cyclic transition state is just a temporary relief for the electrophile that's just been added. The π molecular orbital donates electrons to the electrophile.

While the p-orbitals in the π-bond overlap with the electrophile, each p-orbital forms a σ-bond.

> But would the same thing happen if I put any other electrophile?

Generally,electrophilic addition reactions take place through carbocation intermediate.
But this reaction can take place through cyclic 3-membered intermediate,if the electrophile has a lone pair.

Apart from $\ce{Cl+,Br+}$ even $\ce{Hg^2+}$ (when the reagent is $\ce{Hg(OAc)2/H3O+}$) and $\ce{NO+}$ (when the reagent is $\ce{NOCl}$) can form the 3-membered cyclic intermediate.

Comment: This is my first answer.Can anyone verify whether what I have written is correct? Please suggest some tips on answering and tell what I can improve on,so that I can write better answers in the future.Thanks :)

Comment: Include references if you have them

Comment: thanks at lot actually this helped :)

Comment: @Waylander,Thanks for the suggestion.Unfortunately,I don't have any such references for this.If you have them, you can add them so that the answer is complete.Thanks

Comment: @ganuwoahh Thanks for the feedback.It's nice to hear that it helped you :)